# Pivot table not updating new data but other pivots on the same spreadsheet do

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have one excel document with 3 different pivot tables that pull different columns from the same data source. I updated the data source so it included new data that has been added after 12/23 and then refreshed the pivot tables. Two of the pivots work perfectly, but there's on that instead of showing Quarter 1, and then Jan and Feb it displays >12/31/2023 instead of adding a row for 2024, Q1 and then Jan and Feb
[image]

I noticed that on the pivot tables that are working properly the auto grouping is checked off for both starting at and ending at fields, the ending at field automatically took the last date entered in that column.
[image]

I also noticed that when I check the Pivot Table Fields for the pivot tables that are updating properly the dates are group by month
[image]

When I check the auto grouping for the pivot that is not updating properly it is not pulling the latest date and ending at is not checked off. When I check off the ending date and put a recent date  the Pivot Table Field no longer is grouping by months but by dates

[image]

[image]

After that the pivot does update with 2024, Q1, Jan and Feb but it removes the pivot table field that I selected for the row and put in parentheses with the grouping.

[image]

[image]

The issue is that I need that main Pivot Table Field because it is part of a formula for other spreadsheets.

The correct way should be:
[image]

-Compared the pivot that is not working with the ones that are pulling the data
-Checked that all dates are valid
-Confirmed that the data source is the same all pivots
-Deleted the cache both in Excel and the temporary files
-Deleted and created from scratch the pivot table
-Copied one of the other pivot tables that is working properly but even though the dates are pulling correctly as soon as I change it to the other pivot table field the same issue happens.